# How can I convert this object to an array and access values by key in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, redux

**I have an Object with a lot of keys. I need to convert this object to an array of objects but in such a way where I can still access the values for each object by the key.**

**I want to go from:**

```
{'A': 123, 'B': 453, 'C': 4132}
```

**To:**

```
[{'A': 123}, {'B': 453}, {'C': 4132}]
```

**I want to be able to access the values with a key such as `'A'` or `'B'` to return `123` and `453` respectively.**

I am using Redux and currently my reducer looks like so:

```
const contextReducer = (state=null, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'CONTEXTUALIZE':
            state =  Object.values(action.payload)
            state = state.filter(o => (o === state[0] || o === state[3]))
            state = Object.assign(...state)
            console.log(state)
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default contextReducer
```

I have tried using `Object.values(state)` again right before the `return` but this gives me an array of items like so:

```
['A', 123, 'B', 453, 'C', 4132]
```

Comment: If you turn it into an array of objects you can't access the objects inside it with keys, but only with numeric indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to render the `state` object, or parts of it, in a sort of drop-down style way, you can keep the `state` object as is and iterate over the keys and values of `state` when rendering and pass each key-value pair to a child component.

For example:

```js
render() {
    // ... get `state` from redux

    return (
        <div>
            { Object.keys(state).map(key => (
                <MyComponent key={ key } stateKey={ key } stateValue={ state[key] }/>
            ) }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note: We're using both the props `key` and `stateKey` because the `key` prop is the special prop for identity in React, and `stateKey` will be the one used inside of `MyComponent`.

**Original Answer:**

Instead of trying to iterate over the values of the `state` object (with `Object.values(state)`), you can use the keys, with `Object.keys(state)`, and then access each value using the key with `state[key]`. Iterate over the keys with a `map` call and convert each key to an object containing the single key and its corresponding value.

```js
Object.keys(state).map(key => ({[key]: state[key]}))
```

Result:

```js
[ { A: 123 }, { B: 453 }, { C: 4132 } ]
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much, but what is the best way to now access the values within each object in the new array of objects? I'd like to be able to access them by key name

Comment: @Alex If you want to access the values by key, you won't be able to directly with this array, so you'd be better off sticking with the original object. However, you could make use of the `find` method of the array, but note that this has a time complexity of `O(n)` compared to `O(1)` for accessing values in an object by their keys, but if the array isn't too big, that isn't really an issue. Does that seem like what you're after?

Comment: [ { A: 123 }, { B: 453 }, { C: 4132 } ].find(value => value[key] )

Comment: @HenryWoody well the array is not super massive, approximately  200 items. Since I cannot access the array by key by keeping it as an object because ```Objects are not valid as React child```. So I am not sure what else to do. I'm not sure how I can really use the find method for arrays when I am trying to render values from my object. This does not seem like a very readable options.

Comment: @Alex Oh, I see, so the issue is really just in the rendering then. If you want to display this `state` object in your app, I'd say keep the object as is and then when you render it, call `JSON.stringify(state)` so that you're actually passing a string, but it'll render just the same.

Comment: Ahh...interesting. Is this truly the best way to do this? The reason I have this object is because it is filled with all the data I fetch from an API and need to be able to render exactly what I choose based on a key.

Comment: @Alex If you have something like `<div>{ state }</div>` in your code, then I'd say yes this is the best way since you'll only be changing `state` for presentation purposes and you can still work with it as you would naturally in the code. Also makes it easier if you wanted to switch to displaying it as a table or something down the line, for example.

Comment: Well, I'd have to use ```JSON.stringify(state)```. I'm surprised there is not a cleaner way to do this instead of ```stringify``` after using keys to access a value....especially if I have so many keys.

Comment: @Alex it's possible I'm misunderstanding the question a bit. Do you want to display the whole `state` object to the user or only certain key/values?

Comment: @HenryWoody I do not want to display all of ```state```. I'd like to only display specific values determined by the key that I chose in  in one of my components--a list of expansion panels.

Comment: The user will ultimately see them all, but not in one place. Each expansion panel would display specific key values pairs.

Comment: @Alex okay so that's why you wanted the array, so you can pass each sub object (originally key/value pair) to a different component. Then I'd suggest a somewhat similar approach of leaving `state` as is, but then in your `render` method, iterate over the values, but pass key/value to the component. For example `Object.keys(state).map(key => <MyComponent objKey={ key } objValue={ state[key] }/>)`. Seem more like what you're after?

Comment: @HenryWoody, yes ultimately that is what I would like to do! I did not realize I am not forced to use an array for this.  Is that correct? In your example above is ```state``` and object?

Comment: @Alex yeah in that last comment that `state` is the original (object) version of state. I'll update the answer if that looks good.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is unfortunately not directly possible. Arrays in JS can only be accessed by integer indices.

I don't know the specifics of why you need this behavior, but I would advise you to
store an object in Redux and then create function, which can transform it into shape you want.

Using your example above that would be:

```
state = {'A': 123, 'B': 453, 'C': 4132}

const objectAsArrayOfEntries = (obj) => 
      (Object.entries(obj).map(entry => {entry[0]: entry[1]})
```

Here I used [Object.entries()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-entries-javascript/) function, which returns an array of [key, value] arrays, which gives a close representation of what you're looking for.

Comment: Well the reason I am trying to do this is because I want to be able to render very specific values based on a key from my object. The object contains all the data I fetch from an API. I am unsure of a better way to do this but I'm sure there has to be.